# How to initialize a std::vector with different size after declaration in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I need to do something like following:

```
vector<int> v;
int flag = 0;

if (flag) {
// initialize v with size 100;
} else {
// initialize v with size 0;
}
...
if (flag) {
// do something with v, given flag != 0
} else {
// don't do with v.
}
```

What's the right way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: If you need `v` only in the true branch, why not declare it there?

Comment: Use `std::vector.resize(size_t)`. Also, see comment from @chris

Comment: @chris, thanks. Because I may use ``v`` in later part of code (given ``flag != 0``). In this case, could I still declare ``v`` in the true branch?

Comment: @AaronZeng: in that case, I'd consider putting the true and false branches in separate functions. If you have a lot of code in common, then you can have a mini-struct with the common code and function calls for the `if-else` parts. This has the advantage that now you'll only test `flag` once (and create / call the appropriate static member fn, i.e., `if(flag) { DoSomething<true>::something(); } else { DoSomething<false>::something(); }`). Welcome to the world of static polymorphism :).

Comment: @AaronZeng, The comment in the false branch misled me.

Comment: my bad, @chris. I corrected that. Sorry I didn't say it clearly at first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`std::vector::resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) function to do it:

```
if (flag) {
     v.resize(100);
} else {
     // Don't need v at all; initialize v with size 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't show the full picture. I need to use v in later part of code (given ``flag != 0``). In this case, could I still declare v in the true branch as a local variable?

Comment: @AaronZeng No in this case use the 1st variant.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this.

```
vector<int> v;

if (condition) {
    v = vector<int>(size, 0);
    // resize the vector of to 'size' and initialize it with 0.
}
else {
    v.resize(size, 0);
    // does the same
}
```